# Couldnt push Sharkbite connector all the way for one pipe

Tags: plumbing

I just finish installing my water softener in my house's PEX plumbing, I was able to push all the pipes all the way till it reach the depth length indicated by the sharkbite deburring/depth tool, except for one:

https://ibb.co/zZkCpsD. You can see a black line drawn by me, there is a gap. I push really hard I just can't push it all the way in, not sure if I drew the line wrong or something is wrong. Is there a way to tell if I drew the line too far without pulling it out?

I turned my water back on, and had the water softener do regeneration for 2 hours, no leak. Should I still redo that section? If I redo, I will have to cut some part of the gray pipe and add another pipe in, which mean an extra sharkbite. If I don't, is there anything I can put outside that can prevent leak better?

I also read a lot of people badmouthing sharkbites, is it really that bad even if I dont use them for inwall pipes?

Answer (score 1):

Many plumbers badmouth them but in my experience they work very well. I couldn't view the pic you loaded but as long as it's close to the correct depth you should be fine. If you're not sure there is a sharkbite removal tool that you can use to remove the fitting and then reassemble it.
[image]
BTW - It's easy to learn how to sweat a fitting. There are several youtube videos that explain proper technique. It'll pay off in the long run to spend a little time now learning a new skill.

Comment: Oh yea I got that removal tool too, but I was afraid the pipe and sharkbite wont work as well if I do pull it out and reinsert it, is my concern necessary??  
Yeah I wish I did more research on other method beforehand, I actually would have went the PEX pipe Crimp route. It would be so much easier, the sharkbite push was really tough for me in certain spot, and I would be more confident with crimp :(.

Comment: No problem with uninstalling and reinserting it - I've done it before. The main thing with sharkbites is to follow directions. Be sure to debur the end.

Comment: Thanks, regarding deburring. So all my pipe are PEX, and the ones I bought I was able to deburr it (using the orange sharkbite depth tool), it trimmed the outside edge, so if u look on the side, you will see the outside edge is slanted a bit. Now the existing PEX in my house, I tried to deburr it but it make it worse, the edge become a lot rougher. So in the end I deburred the PEX i added to my plumbing, but didnt deburr the existing one because when I use my pex cutter it cut very square and even. And they say only copper pipe need deburring with i use a proper cutter. Does that sound ok?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you drew the line in the wrong spot. Your tubing looks like 3/4" CTS and that needs to be inserted 1.13" into the fitting. The way the piping has been installed, it has passed the grab ring and the sealing "o" ring so you should have a good connection.

I don't use Sharkbite connectors because I'm a big fan of sweating pipes but I have helped people install them because I'm a nice guy. They are great for DIYers but they have to be installed correctly and many people using them don't follow the directions exactly and have problems. I think the plumbers don't like them because they are easy to use and they lose business.

Comment: yea you are right it's a 3/4". Thanks for your input! I guess I will keep it as it for now